# Как прочитать название приходящих переменных из POST или GET?

Tags: php, api

Есть система, в ней есть настройка полей карточки контакта.

1) есть таблица contact в ней id и прочие поля. 
2) есть таблица input_check в ней есть поле id, title_input, vid_input
3) есть таблица content_input, где есть поля id, id_input_check, id_contact, content_input

Получается открывая карточку клиента из таблицы input_check  виды полей, потом по видам и id клиента вытягивает данные из таблицы content_input и поля content_input.

Нужно заносить новые контакты через API.

Например: Приходит в API `$_POST['input_970']`, где 970 это ID поля input_check

Мне надо через API прочитать все приходящие переменные вытащить из названия переменной ID вида поля. Потом из таблицы input_check вытащить id видов и потом подставить их при добавлении в таблицу content_input вместе данными и данными пришедшими в $_POST['input_970'] и id контакта.

**Как прочитать в названии переменной ID?**

Comment: Честно сказать - вопрос не понял...

Comment: @DNS ну вот в API приходят данные например так POST['input_970'] как мне вытащить ID (970) из названия переменной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
$tempArr = array_keys($_POST);
$id = 0;
foreach($tempArr as $value){
   if(substr($value, 0, 6) == 'input_'){
       $id = str_replace('input_', '', $value);
   }
}
```

Comment: супер! уже нашел правда, но все равно благодарю!

Comment: Если у тебя придет в массиве $_POST еще какая то инфа - то твой метод может дать не правильный результат

Comment: например какая инфа?

Comment: Допустим по каким то причинам тебе придет $_POST['input_970'] и тут же $_POST['wtfsdfinput_970'] и еще что нибудь. А тебе нужно выбрать из всего что пришло именно твой id и именно из строки input_970

Comment: Ну я защиту поставлю. если человек сделал как вы описали ну это его проблема, просто данные в поле не попадут. =)